# Stylus s() & +cache blocks ignore media queries

Tags: css, media-queries, stylus

I am noticing stylus is applying my +cache code in the incorrect block. The styles that are supposed to be only display on the tablet media queries gets displayed instead on the non-cached scope.

It looks like an issue with Stylus' `s()` function not recognizing if it's inside a media block and just printing out the CSS

```
// styles
.content
    width 70% // mobile devices

    +media('sm') // tablet devices
        width calc('100% - ' + em($photo-size))
```

Here is my calc mixin

```
calc()
    if current-property
        for prefix in vendors
            arguments = unquote(arguments)
            add-property(current-property[0], s('-%s-calc(%s)', prefix, arguments))
        s('calc(%s)', arguments)
    else
        error('calc() must be used within a property')
```

This cache implementation was copied over from http://kizu.ru/en/issues/new-stylus-features/

```
// Mixin for caching the blocks with the given conditions
media($condition)
    helper($condition)
        unless $media_cache[$condition]
            $media_cache[$condition] = ()
        push($media_cache[$condition], block)

    +helper($condition)
        {selector() + ''}
            {block}

// Function we would use to call all the cached styles
apply_media_cache()
    for $media, $blocks in $media_cache
        $media = unquote($media_aliases[$media] || $media)
        $media = '(%s)' % $media unless match('\(', $media)
        $media = 'only screen and %s' % $media
        @media $media
            for $block in $blocks
                {$block}
```

The outputted CSS looks like

```
.content
    width: 70%;
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 8.928571428571429em);
    width: -moz-calc(100% - 8.928571428571429em);
    width: -ms-calc(100% - 8.928571428571429em);
```

When it should be

```
@media (…tablet-size…)
    .content
        width: -webkit-calc…
        …
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an already fixed issue which only related to Stylus 0.49.x which is used by the previous version of grunt-contrib-stylus. Updating grunt stylus to version 0.21.0 fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

Dewd, just use [Rupture](http://jenius.github.io/rupture/) for your media queries. I can see that you have all kinds of awesome things going on between that mixin and function, but I think what you're trying to do has already been solved by rupture. Good luck!

Comment: Cool library, unfortunately no beans :(

Comment: Sorry. So, I tired to fire the code up using https://learnboost.github.io/stylus/try.html but it wouldn't output anything. Is there anything else needed to run the code?

Comment: Thanks for the attempt but as it turns out, this is an already fixed issue which only related to Stylus 0.49.x